# CSS set absolute position

Tags: css, css-position

When I set `position: absolute` and `top: 0px` the element does not actually positions absolutely, but it positions relatively to its parent (with `position: relative`).

Is there a simple way to set element position relative to the whole document not to the parent?

**UPDATE**

Can I do this if my element is already attached to a div with `position:relative`?
It's a problem to reattach element to the body in my case.

Comment: Put it out of any parent div , only to be in the body.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your div to be positioned absolute to parent than simply place it between the `<body>` tag (Here I assume that you are using `position: relative` for `body`) and not inside any positioned relative child element else your positioned absolute div will be positioned absolute to that element and not the body(Which you are referring as parent here)

Comment: @AndreyMinogin position absolute has no relation with other element unless and until it is in a positioned relative div, absolute divs are out of the document flow

Comment: @AndreyMinogin If you want absolute to parent, there is no question of I CANNOT DO IT, it is absolute, place it anywhere but inside body tag and not any child of body. If you still need it, use higher negative top, right bottom left

Answer (score 1):

An element with a position: absolute will position itself absolutely to the first parent element with another position style.

You need to bring the element outside any elements with position styles. You may as well put it at the end of the body HTML if it's going to be positioned absolutely anyway.